# python logspace curve generation

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, logarithm

I would like to generate a logarithmic curve between two values, with a set number of datapoints in between.

I tried `np.logspace(start,end,num_points)` but that has an issue:
The created values are much higher than I expected (I believe this is due to the base value?)

How can I create values to be in the input range (with the distance between them being logarithmic)? i.e.
`start=10; end=12; num_points=6` 
output: `array([10, 11, 11.5, 11.75, 11,9, 12])`
(the numbers in the output are just my estimation, real values will be different).

My end goal is to plot these values (y-axis) against the num_points (as x-axis).
`plt.plot(num_point,output)`

Comment: Have you read the docstring of `logspace`? No? at any rate, try `np.logspace(np.log10(10), np.log10(12), 6)`

Comment: This is the output: `array([10., 10.37137289, 10.75653757, 11.15600622, 11.57031005, 12.])`<br>
I think this is linear. I'd like to have the first values rise fast and then start getting slower

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can log a `linspace` with start and end points raised correspondingly:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.plot(range(6), [10, 11, 11.5, 11.75, 11.9, 12], 'ko-', label='requested')
plt.plot(range(6), np.log10(np.linspace(10**10, 10**12, 6)), 'ro-', label='log10')
plt.plot(range(6), np.log(np.linspace(np.exp(10), np.exp(12), 6)), 'bo-', label='log')
plt.legend()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for [geomspace](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.geomspace.html), e.g.

```py
import numpy as np
print(np.geomspace(10, 12, 6))
#[10.         10.37137289 10.75653757 11.15600622 11.57031005 #12.        ]
```

Comment: thanks. i think its very similar to gboffi's suggestion, but it is still rathar linear progression. What I was looking for is more similar to what [@Stef](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3944322/stef) suggested.

its actually good to know that your implementation (geospace) has similar ouput as logspace with log10...

Comment: In your original post  you steted `How can I create values to be in the input range (with the distance between them being logarithmic)?`, which is exactly what geomspace does. Ofcourse on can transform the input and use lin or log space, but geomspace does exactly what you asked. From the docs geomspace `Return numbers spaced evenly on a log scale (a geometric progression).`